# Open a web page in Google Chrome without activating it

Tags: macos, applescript, high-sierra, google-chrome

Sometimes I want to open a web page in Google Chrome, but without switching to the browser. I have an applescript command (`osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome"  to open location "URL"'`) to open a web page, but it activates the browser. Is there a way to open a web page in the browser without activating it?

The script below opens the link with no errors but activates Google Chrome. I'm not sure why is that the case.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "chrome://settings" without activating
end tell
```

Comment: `without activating` is not a valid _argument_ of the `open location` _verb_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may have been a time when **Google Chrome** was compliant with **AppleScript** *commands* e.g. `run` or `launch`, which would keep it in the background, as it does with e.g. **Safari** and other *applications*. Or compliant with with the *shell* `open` *command* using either the `-g` or `-j` *options* along with the `-a` *option*.

In testing under **macOS Catalina** I could not get **Google Chrome** to consistently open in the background and only with the `open` *command* with `-jga` would it open in the background a few different times, but not at all consistently.

**Google** clearly is not conforming to the **macOS** norms!

That said, the only way I could consistently open a **URL** in **Google Chrome** in the background was is if it was already running with an open *window* in the background.

I'll post the *example* **AppleScript** *code* just for you to test if it works for you as it did for me.

```applescript
set myURL to "https://www.example.com"

if running of application "Google Chrome" then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if window 1 exists then
            tell window 1
                make new tab
                repeat while (loading of active tab)
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                execute active tab javascript "document.location.href = '" & myURL & "';"
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
end if
```